# Keep flex items fixed while resizing window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a web app and I need help with css. I am a beginner at css so please bear with me.

I'm trying to style a fixed sidebar for an app. The sidebar occupies the full height of the browser window. The whole sidebar is a flex box and the flex children are nested flex boxes as well.

Presently, the flex children move along with the browser window while reducing the viewport height and so the menu links get pushed up (but the avatar and username element remain fixed?!).

I don't want this to happen. The menu items inside the parent container should get clipped (instead of moving along with the browser window) and the user can scroll down to view the remaining menu items (like the sidebar on the youtube website for example).

For easy reference, here is the imgur link of what is current result and what I actually want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG7XE.jpg

Also, the scroll bar seems to take up extra width while appearing. Is there any way to stop that behavior?

https://jsfiddle.net/qbw1aLyz/8/

```css
html {
  background-color: #141E30;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #0a0c0f;
  color: #EAE9E9;
}

.sidebar__profile {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar__menuitem {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

.count {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background-color: #EAE9E9;
  color: #0a0c0f;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar__profile">
    <img src="http://chittagongit.com//images/avatar-icon/avatar-icon-4.jpg" height=50px alt="image" class="sidebar__profile__avatar" />
    <div class="sidebar__profile__name">User Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
    <div>Menu Item 1</div>
    <div class="count">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
    <div>Menu Item 2</div>
    <div class="count">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
    <div>Menu Item 3</div>
    <div class="count">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
    <div>Menu Item 4</div>
    <div class="count">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
    <div>Menu Item 5</div>
    <div class="count">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
    <div>Menu Item 6</div>
    <div class="count">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
    <div>Menu Item 7</div>
    <div class="count">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm actually not able to reproduce the issue. I'm seeing the menu items get clipped in Firefox/Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap .sidebar__profile in another div so it can act as a block-element rather than a shrinking flex-element...

```css
html {
  background-color: #141E30;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #0a0c0f;
  color: #EAE9E9;
}

.sidebar__profile {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar__menuitem {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

.count {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background-color: #EAE9E9;
  color: #0a0c0f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div>
        <div class="sidebar__profile">
          <img src="http://chittagongit.com//images/avatar-icon/avatar-icon-4.jpg" height=50px alt="image" class="sidebar__profile__avatar" />
          <div class="sidebar__profile__name">User Name</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 1</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 2</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 3</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 4</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 5</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 6</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar__menuitem">
        <div>Menu Item 7</div>
        <div class="count">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both the answers worked. Could you please tell me how to avoid the scroll bar offsetting the numbers near the right side of the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the menu items in their own container, giving that container a scrolling function, and disabling shrinking on the profile.

Add this to your code:

```
nav {
  overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar__profile {
  align-self: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

[revised jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mzw0c6ts/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Both the answers worked. Could you please shed some light upon how to avoid the scroll bar offsetting the numbers near the right side of the sidebar?

Comment: @gameboynintendocolor since you are using fixed width you can try this: https://jsfiddle.net/qkvenxzb/